# Getting org.jbehave.core.io.StoryResourceNotFound error while executing Jbehave stories using Meta tags after updating Jbehave version from 4.1 to 4.6

Tags: jbehave

I am trying to execute Jbehave stories using Meta tags, it was working fine while using Jbehave version 4.1. Once I updated Jbehave version to 4.6, Meta tags are not getting picked up and error is thrown- org.jbehave.core.io.StoryResourceNotFound.

Its not able to locate stories.

Versions used:

Java - 1.8
Jbehave - 4.6
Serenity-jbehave - 1.46.0
Serenity - ant.version - 1.1.36
Spring version - 1.5.14
Serenity-core - 2.2.1

Tried different Jbehave versions after 4.1, but facing same issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.